# Getting different colour backgrounds to scroll up

Tags: swift

I am coding for my A2 coursework project, and making a well-known game 'Fall Down'. However i am trying to get the background to change every cycle while it scrolls - so it changes from blue to red to yellow etc. However when I run it, this only works for the first two colours, then flashes back to the first colour. Here is the code i currently have

```
var background = SKSpriteNode()




override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {



    let blueTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BlueBackground")
    let redTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "RedBackground")
    let yellowTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "YellowBackground")
    let greenTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "GreenBackground")
    let purpleTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "PurpleBackground")
    let TextureArray = [blueTexture, redTexture, yellowTexture, greenTexture, purpleTexture]

    let levelProgress = SKAction.moveByX(0, y:blueTexture.size().height, duration: 5)
    let newLevel = SKAction.moveByX(0 , y: -blueTexture.size().height, duration: 0)
    let sequenceForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([ levelProgress,  newLevel]))

    var a = 0

    for var i: CGFloat = 0; i<5; i++ {
        let currentBG = TextureArray[a]
        a++
        background = SKSpriteNode(texture: currentBG)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: -blueTexture.size().height/2 + blueTexture.size().height * i)
        background.size.width = self.frame.width
        background.runAction(sequenceForever)

        self.addChild(background)

    }
```

if anyone could point me in the right direction or if any more information is needed let me know! This is my first post so any posting advice would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

It might by because of this:

```
let levelProgress = SKAction.moveByX(0, y:blueTexture.size().height, duration: 5)
let newLevel = SKAction.moveByX(0 , y: -blueTexture.size().height, duration: 0)
let sequenceForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([ levelProgress,  newLevel]))

background.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: -blueTexture.size().height/2 + blueTexture.size().height * i
```

you always use the blueTexture.size. try to change it to a constant value.

Comment: Ok i will give that a look through - Thanks for your help and yes i will do just trying to get it to work first!